# In Doctor Strange, what was the title of the book Stan Lee was reading in his cameo?

Tags: story-identification, marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange-2016

I'm really curious as to the title of the book Stan Lee was reading in his cameo appearance in *Doctor Strange*. Is was relevant to the story, and I tried to make a mental note of it, but that mental note was totally lost in the crazy mind trip that followed.

[image]

Comment: [*The Doors of Perception.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Doors_of_Perception) [Cross-site dupe.](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62878/what-was-stan-lees-character-reading-on-the-bus-in-doctor-strange)

Comment: You might find it interesting to learn that his cameo (and a bunch of others) have been pre-filmed in front of a green screen. The Director was given a selection to choose from, then added Strange in digitally afterwards.

Comment: @Valorum I'm very interested in learning more about these canned cameos! Do you have a link with more information? I can only find a bunch of articles all talking about Stan filming this and three others in the same day but they were all specific to each movie.

Comment: @JDoe - This is the article I was thinking of. There's nothing in it to suggest that his cameos were specific to each film; http://ew.com/article/2016/10/29/james-gunn-stan-lee-marvel-cameos/

Comment: @Valorum Thanks for that! But it links to an LAT story where Feige confirms those cameos were each specific to a film. http://www.latimes.com/entertainment/movies/la-et-mn-stan-lee-marvel-cameos-20160928-snap-story.html

Comment: @JDoe - The fact that it was green-screened tells me that they're being a bit economical with the truth :-)

Comment: @Valorum I suppose we'll find out for certain after the cosmic Ragnarok and Volume 2 come out. It will be very suspicious if he's in Earth costumes in both films.

Answer (score 64):

[Doors of perception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Doors_of_Perception) by Aldous Huxley.

[image]

Its a well known book about "expanding mind" using mescaline and other halucinogenic drugs, which author describes as almost religous in their nature. This book became some sort of bible in the 60s, Jim Morrison called his band after this book.

It is quite fitting, since we can see it during pretty "tripping" scene

Comment: Excellent and thorough answer. I would up vote if I had enough reputation.

Comment: @ChristopherHunter then click the green check mark next to the question to indicate it helped you.

Comment: Also see this answer, which adds in reasoning why it might have been an inside joke: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62878/what-was-stan-lees-character-reading-on-the-bus-in-doctor-strange

Comment: @Majaii - It's not much of an inside joke. The scene wasn't specifically filmed for Doctor Strange, it was filmed along with about twenty other cameos and the Director was then given a selection to pick from.

Comment: Nice update with the exact same book cover!

Comment: @Valorum - Huh, didn't know they did it that way, cool.

Comment: @Yasskier - It's still not exactly right. In the edition in the film, the title is at the top with the author name at the bottom.